# How to make a filter in a model (Django/ORM) respecting the place of the fields in the query?

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, query-optimization

I have a model `Student` with this fields: `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`. I added a compose index with `first_name` and `last_name`.

The problem is when i filter. I use `Student.objects.filter(last_name='Caicedo', first_name='Pedro')` but the internal ORM select is:

```
SELECT `students`.`id`, `students`.`first_name`, `students`.`last_name` 
FROM `students` 
WHERE (`students`.`first_name` = 'Pedro' AND `students`.`last_name` = 'Caicedo'); args=('Pedro', 'Caicedo');
```

It does not respect the order, and I need to respect it by optimizing the query.

Comment: I think you're trying to solve a nonexistent problem. Notice that if you have an index on `(last_name, first_name)` and your query contains `WHERE first_name = 'Pedro' AND last_name = 'Caicedo'` the query uses the index correctly. The query planner is smart enough to place your WHERE-filters in the correct order to exploit your index.

Comment: Are you sure @O.Jones? because we just have a microservice that was having slow queries, and we were asked from the DB side to perform that specific optimization. It is a MySql DB with innodb engine. We made the upgrade and now go from 350 to 2000 RPM with this optimization.

Comment: In addition to the best practices and optimizations when making queries, it is recommended in the where clause to order between the most specific and the general. So the order does matter when optimizing a query and therefore improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Investigating this can be solved using Q functions. Example:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Student.objects.filter(Q(last_name='Caicedo'), Q(first_name= 'Pedro'))
```

Now my query is correct and I can take advantage of the index created in the table.